Are questions about the publication process in psychology and cognitive science permitted?
I recently asked what I believe is the first question on the site about the publication process rather than about substantive knowledge in psychology and cognitive science.

What are the major changes in the APA Publication Manual from 5th to 6th editions?

I think this is an important question for researchers who are planning to submit journal articles. And likewise, I imagine there would be many other similar questions related to the process of publishing research that would be in scope for this site.
That said, I realise, this is the first time such a question has been asked, so:
Are questions about the publication process in psychology and cognitive science permitted?

It's important for people in the field so I certainly feel it's on topic for the site

It seems fine to me, too. I bet that it wouldn't be difficult to reverse the policy should it get out of hand.

I think it is fine. For precedent, cstheory.SE has plenty of questions about doing research in TCS under tags like advice-request, research-practice, paper-review, and career. On cstheory it has been a great success, as a personal testimonial, I asked a question about publishing preprints in quantum computing and got great answers, with one of them coming from one of the founders of quantum computing. 
Thus, such things can definitely be useful for graduate students. However, I would not encourage these questions at this stage, since they are only useful once you have experts with experience in the field. I think we should build a community first by concentrating on good technical questions.

Note, that I do not think general reference questions about formatting, or APA are on-topic.
